How to use DoF or Hyperfocal calculators with crop factor cameras?
This seems like a stupid question, but I am not sure of the correct answer.
There are various calculators out there that will determine DoF and hyperfocal distances1 based on the aperture, distance to subject, focal length and sensor size.  This is all well and good.
But if I have a crop sensor camera paired with a full sized sensor lens, what number do I plug in for the focal length?  Is it the "indicated" focal length of the lens, or is it the "effective" focal length (IE indicated x crop factor)?
My assumption is the that I should use the "effective" focal length, but I have nothing to support that belief.

To give a concrete example, my DX camera is a Nikon D7500 (nominal crop factor of 1.5).  My FX lens is a Sigma 150-600.  My subject is a building that I want framed by the moon.  I've previously calculated that I need to be 3,000 m from the building in order to achieve my pre-visualization of the image.
Using my example2 online calculator and f/8 as a reasonable aperture:

With the indicated focal length of 400 mm, the calculator returns a
hyperfocal distance of 1000 m
With the "effective" focal length of 600 mm, the calculator returns
2250 m




Yes I am aware that hyperfocal distance calculations are
problematic.

Not endorsing any particular online calculator.




Does this answer your question: Will the Depth of Field Scales Still Work with a Crop Sensor Camera?

@scottbb That question seems to relate to DoF markings on the lens whereas my main interest is the hyperfocal distance calculation.  I only mentioned DoF because various online calculators also provide it when calculating the hyperlocal distance.  And while I am not trying to plug any specific calculator, this is one example.

@scottbb Also the lens I want to use doesn't have DoF markings on it anyway.

You use the physical focal length.What changes the DoF is that for the same framing you use a shorter lens.

@xenoid the difference in enlargement ratios to get the same display size from different sized sensors also plays a part. That's why the "standard" CoC for FF is 0.030 mm and for APS-C is 0.019 mm, to account for the higher enlargement ratio to the standard display size assumed by most DoF calculators.

If the calculator allows you to specify the camera model, the crop factor, or the circle of confusion (CoC) value; then you enter the lens' actual focal length.
Typically you enter either the camera model or the crop factor; then the calculator uses that information to select the CoC value used in the calculation based on some accepted standards.

However, the "accepted standards" are not really standards at all, and they are arguably outdated/weak... e.g. based on "average visual acuity" (~20/40 vision). Your specific use case may require a different CoC value be used for the calculation.
Understand that depth of field is not a fixed aspect of an image; it is dependent on magnification/enlargement. So if you crop an image in post it affects the depth of field exactly the same as using a crop sensor does. I.e. if cropping a full frame image to the DX area in post, then the DX CoC standard (.02 mm) would be a better choice for the calculation. And if "pixel peeping," then a much more stringent CoC value would be required.
The use of a calculator is kind of pointless unless you know, and can control, all of the other factors related to the final use case and resulting depth of field.
The only aspect that is fixed is the depth of focus; the relative sharpness at the image plane. That is controlled only by the physical size of the aperture restriction (entrance pupil diameter; not f#). The calculator uses the focal length and f# to determine this value; if you entered an effective focal length it would alter the results.
Using the effective focal length instead to alter the CoC value is valid; but I don't think I have ever seen it used in that way.

Edit to add:
When using the calculator for hyperfocal distance (HFD), and then trying to estimate the focus setting/distance in the field (as in your example), it is best to estimate long... estimating the distance accurately is difficult.
If you focus long the near edge of the calculated DoF will never be farther than the HFD itself (i.e. 1000m w/ the 400/f8). In that case it may be best to focus on the subject at 3000m for maximal sharpness at that point, and increased sharpness of the moon. This is where the "focus at 2/3" rule of thumb comes from...

I understand the problems with the hyperfocal distance calculation, but for this shoot (see my update with a concrete example) I believe it's about the best that I can achieve.  My takeaway from your answer though is use the lens' actual focal length in these calculators.  Correct?

@PeterM, correct

@PeterM, when using the calculator for hyperfocal distance, and then trying to estimate the focus setting/distance in the field (as in your example), it is best to estimate long... estimating the distance accurately is difficult. If you focus long the short side of the calculated DoF will never be farther than the HFD itself (i.e. 1000m w/ the 400/f8). In that case it may be best to focus on the subject at 3000m for maximal sharpness at that point, and increased sharpness of the moon. This is where the "focus at 2/3" rule of thumb comes from...

I'll take that advice!  I do have GPS locations for where I want to stand, based on being 3,000m from the subject, but it is pure empty space between me and the main subject.  I also have a collection of really really bad shots I took in July at various focal lengths, and I am using them now to decide how to frame my shot.  Next is balancing the FL, aperture, exposure and DoF.

Focal length is focal length. It is a property of the lens that describes how strong it's refractive property is. Always use the actual focal length of the lens when using Depth of Field calculators.
"Effective focal length" is only useful for giving an estimate of the angle of view a lens gives on a sensor other than one that is "Full frame" size (i.e. 36x24mm).
Cambridge in Color has a Depth of Field calculator that allows one to input planned display size and viewing distance, as well as focal length, aperture, and sensor size, into the calculation. Click on the "show advanced" hyperlink to reveal the additional entry fields.
And for what it's worth, you get the same exact angle of view on an APS-C sensor with an APS-C lens as you do with a full frame lens of the same actual focal length. This is because they're both the same focal length and both must be multiplied by the crop factor to see what focal length you'd need to get the equivalent angle of view on a FF camera.
When working with hyperfocal distances, always keep in mind that display size and viewing distance affect depth of field, and thus affect hyperfocal distance. If the DoF calculator you're using does not provide input for display size and viewing distance, it's probably assuming "standard" conditions: an 8x10 or 8x12 print viewed at a distance of 10-12 inches (by a person with 20/20 vision). If you double the display size and view at the same distance, all of the blur in the photo will be enlarged and the DoF will shrink. Since hyperfocal distance is based on putting the rear edge of the DoF at infinity, if the DoF shrinks then the focus distance must be increased to put the rear edge of the DoF back to infinity.
When considering display size, also remember that if you zoom in to "100%" on your monitor, you're viewing a small piece of an image whose magnification is much larger than the size of your monitor. When viewing even a 24MP image at 100% on a 24" Full HD monitor, you're looking at a piece of a roughly 62 x 41 inch enlargement!
